# How to have a Function returning an array which starts at index 0

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have a function which returns an array:

```
PURE FUNCTION set_Xgrid() RESULT(x_grid)                                                            
    REAL(dp), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: x_grid                                                           
    INTEGER :: ii                                                                                   

    ALLOCATE(x_grid(0:Nx-1))                                                                        

    DO ii=0,Nx-1                                                                                    
        x_grid(ii) = x_o + ii*dx                                                                    
    END DO                                                                                          
END FUNCTION
```

I then just call this function like this:

```
REAL(dp), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: x                                                            

ALLOCATE(x(0:Nx-1))                                                                                  
x = set_Xgrid()    

DO ii=0,Nx-1                                                                                     
    PRINT '(I4,A10,F10.7)', ii, ", x(ii) = ", x(ii)                                              
END DO
```

Output (first few lines):

```
   0, x(ii) =  0.0000000
   1, x(ii) =  0.0101010
   2, x(ii) =  0.0202020
```

Even though the above code works as expected, I do not really understand how it works.

I thought the `RESULT` of a function was an implicit `INTENT(OUT)` and worked the same way: any value prior to the call of the function was ignored and the variable was automatically deallocated. If that is the case, the code somehow remembers that the variable `x` was initialized starting at index 0.

Is this the right way to have the returned array of a function start at index 0? Also, I'd like to understand what happens when a function returns an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vladimir F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409575) covers much of what you need to know.  There is more detail to add, however.

It is important to repeat, first, that a function result is not at all like an `intent(out)` dummy variable.  Except in cases that don't apply here the function result acts as an expression rather than a variable.

You ask

> If that is the case, the code somehow remembers that the variable x was initialized starting at index 0.

This is a consequence of the rules of intrinsic assignment (see, for example, 7.2.1.3 of Fortran 2008).  If the variable on the left of the assignment is an allocatable variable it *may* be deallocated first.  This "may" is important: it isn't always deallocated.

If the variable array is deallocated then it will be reallocated with the bounds/shape of the expression on the right.  The lower bound of the expression will be `1` regardless of the bounds of the function result.

However, in your case the shape of the variable array is the same as the shape of the expression.  Here, the variable is not deallocated before it is reallocated.  It thus keeps its original bounds (lower bound `0`).

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, my allocatable array is not deallocated because it has the same shape as my function result. Is that guaranteed? Or is it possible a different compiler (or same compiler with different flags) decides to deallocate it upon the function call? This may be a source of trouble as the lower bound of my returned array will be `1`

Comment: Correct.  That is the behaviour specified by the standard, but compilers may have bugs...  And in more exotic cases (not applicable here either) deallocation may occur even with the same shape.  Again, see the linked rules for details of those.

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure there is no deallocation, and that the variable is the same shape as the expression, then you can use the array section on the left-hand side: `X(:) = set_Xgrid()`.  This thing on the left is not allocatable.

Comment: Interesting... Understanding the details really is important. Thanks!

Comment: Do you always refer yourself to the standard documentation to learn these things? Not coming from a CS background myself, I find it difficult to understand.

Comment: The standard is too difficult for beginners, a textbook should be used for learning. The standard is for confirming some details.

Comment: @VladimirF ha I recently stopped considering myself a beginner since I've been using Fortran for about 2 years. But I guess I never learned it from a proper source (e.g. textbook)

Comment: It is very difficult to get a holistic understanding from the standard, so textbooks are still vital.  Many use the annotations from the standard nearly verbatim but they still provide much-needed context and links across concepts.

Comment: Well I would consider myself a beginner in certain aspects of Fortran even now. When a new standard  comes or when I start working with features I never used before I always read a textbook, a tutorial or an informal text from the standard committee like ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/n1701-n1750/n1729.pdf . The standard is not meant for learning new stuff.

Comment: @VladimirF Indeed - I can't imagine trying to understand coarrays from the standard...

Answer (score 2):

There is not much point returning an array starting at a specific index. It is not important anyway:

```
  x(3:5)

  x = f()
```

will work for any function returning the array of the right size 3, even if it starts from 42 inside the function.

It definitely does not work as `intent(out), allocatable` argument. The values are just assigned to the right place of the array, counting from the array start, not using the actual indexes.

If the variable is not allocated at all prior the assignment

```
 real, allocatable :: x(:)
 x = f()
```

then it is allocated to start at 1 with the right size, again, where the result started inside the function does not matter.

Comment: Isn't it redundant to allocate an array, just to have it deallocated and reallocated again?

Comment: The reallocation only happens when the variable you assign to doesn't have the right size (conforming shape). Otherwise it stays allocated as it was. Reallocation every time would be very costly. If you allocate it as `(-1:n)` it stays that way even if you assign something with the same size to it.